# Is grease/oil on thermal pads harmful?

Tags: ssd

I have a Samsung 970 Evo NVMe SSD. These drives usually tend to run hot.
My motherboard is a MSI X570 MAG Tomahawk. I used the heatsink that came with it onto my ssd.

I decided to try another heatsink to see if I could get better cooling performance.  When I removed the heatsink, I saw some grease-like substance onto the thermal pad.

Its not even a month had passed since I used my new build but was shocked to see some grease like substance appear.

I was not sure if it was intended to be there in the first place as I was not the one who installed the Motherboard NVMe heatsink onto my NVMe SSD but consulting from other people, they say it is oil.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/uY2Bw9V.jpg]
[image]

From what I read, [having oils](https://linustechtips.com/topic/1202453-oils-in-my-gpus-thermal-pads/?tab=comments) in the thermal pad may be a sign that the thermal pad is of poor quality as the thermal pad deformed in shape (turning into oil) which then results in bad or no contact with the device that is intended to be cooled. If oils continue to accumulate, they may eventually leak and cause a short which in turn, fry my computer.

I do think that this is oil because judging by the appearance and location of this substance, it is located at where the controller and at the NAND flash chips are placed. Different NVMe SSDs will have different placements of NAND Flash chips and controllers, so it looks to me that the substance made an imprint of the said components on where it was placed along the thermal pad. Since these components both get hot, then it becomes evident that grease/oil starts forming onto the side where the thermal pad makes contact with these components.

Also I don't recall needing to apply any substance when installing anything on top of a thermal pad. AFAIK you just slap it onto a surface when you're ready to place it. I can only therefore deduce that it is oil that formed due to heat and not some pre-applied special lubricant that MSI (the manufacturer of the board) applied.

So I should stop using the NVMe SSD heatsink of my motherboard because it forms harmful oils in the long run that can potentially leak if it accumulates too much?

Edit:
The substance may actually be Silicone gap filler. **DO NOT let it get to your eyes, If it gets to your eyes, you would need to surgically remove it.** Being on the safer side of things, I would advise anyone who experience this to stop using the NVMe SSD Heatsink and just get another one that doesn't leak any oil on the thermal pad. Don't forget to wash your hands thoroughly after handling.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using oil on or around heatsinks. You should use thermal paste between a heatsink and a heat producing part.

You should find out why the SSDs are getting hot. I have two in a desktop computer that runs 24x7 and the SSDs are just warm. No overheating at all. Measured with an accurate IR thermometer.

Measurement with Samsung Magician is 29 degrees C for both drives. No added heat sink. The Samsung drive on my Laptop is running at 39 degrees. Machine is busy working.

Maximum (warning and critical) temperature is 85 degrees C, so up to 50 degrees C operating is well within range.  (General info on the Samsumg site).

Clean the parts thoroughly and where needed apply good thermal paste.

More on not using oil on these parts.

[Description on use of oils][1]

> Oil is a liquid. Heat transfer by conduction requires strong bonds
> between the molecules, so that a vibration(heat) travels down the
> line. With liquids, this does not happen so easily since the
> intermolecular forces are weak.

[1]: [https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/why-is-oil-a-poor-conductor-of-heat#:~:text=Oil%20is%20a%20liquid.,heat](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/23169/why-is-oil-a-poor-conductor-of-heat#:%7E:text=Oil%20is%20a%20liquid.,heat))%20travels%20down%20the%20line.&text=Oil%20should%20still%20be%20able,%22lock%22%20with%20other%20molecules.

Comment: I am not using oil. I did not apply oil onto the thermal pad of my NVMe heatsink. I saw it there coincidentally when I removed it when trying out a new NVMe heatsink.

Comment: I know thermal paste is often referred to as thermal grease but I doubt “thermal grease” has any oil in it. What’s more likely is the substance is from as the author suggested a residue from cheaper thermal paste.

Comment: Clean the parts and apply new paste

Comment: This type of heat pad doesn't use paste, it uses its own 'natural stickiness' to adhere. Clean it & the elctronic components down with isopropyl, refit & check again in a week. If it's producing 'oil' then bin it & buy something better.

Comment: High-performance NVMe SSDs getting quite hot is normal and nothing to worry about (by itself). Of course, proper ventilation is important.

Comment: What "paste" do I apply onto the thermal pad? I only know about the thermal paste used on CPUs. How do I pick which "paste" to apply?

Comment: Just use a good pad for the part..    Also, the drives should remain just warm  (30 - 40 degrees C). Samsung Magician tells me my 2 drives are at 29 degrees C.

Comment: My NVMe SSD drive idles at 39C, goes to around 45-48C when on load and sticks at 51-53C when playing games. Consulting others, they say it is within normal temperature as NAND needs to run hot and I'm still within 0-70C of operating temperature of my Samsung 970 EVO (according to samsung's spec sheet). Also cooling it down to room temperature can risk lowering the data life retention according to JEDEC standards. 

If I want to get close to your 30-40C temps, I would go for water block cooling my NVMe SSD, but that is beyond an average user's reach.

Comment: Max warning and critical temp is 85 degrees C (Samsumg site) and so 50 degrees Operating is well within limits.

Comment: I am currently trying out a new NVMe heatsink I bought which uses a different thermal pad. I only installed it about 2 days ago and will run it for a week. I doubt it will form oils just as my old one shown above. 

With regards to temperatures, its exactly the same but with more pronounced temperature swings depending if I turn on the air conditioning in my room or not (idk why its like this). Anyhow, as long as it does not form those oils, then I would settle for it rather than using a heatsink for a long time and suddenly freaking out with oil leakage.